# Pass the values between two tables

Tags: php, javascript

I develop a transaction function here. But I have a trouble with javascript. As you can see below, there are two table, where the first one is for display the item and the second table is for purchasing. What i want to do is, the row for an item in first table is clickable. When the row is clicked, the item that have been choose come out in the second table. And at the second table cell for discount can be editable and the total price is changing by the discount. Can anyone help me to pass the value between these two tables?

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Item Show</legend>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Item Code</td>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Stock</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['item_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['item_code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['item_manufacturer']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['sell_price']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stock']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Item Sale</legend>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Item name</td>
    <td>Item Code</td>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td>Total Price</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that you should follow.

1. give a common class to all your  like
2. use jQuery events like

   ```
     $(".clickable").on('click',function(e,this){
       //a.use "this" here to extract values that you want to pass to other table
       //b.append <tr><td></td>....</tr> with this.values to your table

   })
   ```

If you can do the above - - things will go fine

Comment: is there any tutorial that might be could help?